# How to dereference old Wildfly 9.0.1 deployment artifacts of Spring MVC app built with intelliJ-IDE?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven, intellij-idea

I'm using intelliJ-IDE-14 to create a SpringMVC project named **`app`** which was initially being deployed to JBoss Wildfly 9.0.1.Final as **`app.war`**

Here's the step by step scenario leading up to my issue;

- After finishing project config to utilize **Maven | Spring | Hibernate | Wildfly | Velocity**, then I made a copy of the project, refactored the new copy as **`demo`** and continued working on **`demo`**. That way, I could always re-use **`app`** as a barebones start-up template.
- With that done, I then continued work on **`demo`**.
- I configured maven to name output war file of **`demo`** to be **`ROOT.war`**
- Also, just so I don't forget, I go back to **`app`** too and configured maven to name output war file of **`app`** as **`ROOT.war`**
- Now I run **`demo`**, it gets deployed, hits the controller and displays landing page. All is fine, except when I check the logs I see the following exceptions being thrown while it is being deployed.

***See StackTrace;***

```
INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYSRV0027: Starting deployment of "app.war" (runtime-name: "app.war")
INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYDS0013: Started FileSystemDeploymentService for directory C:\jBoss\wildfly-9.0.1.Final\standalone\deployments
ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-6) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."app.war".STRUCTURE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."app.war".STRUCTURE: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase STRUCTURE of deployment "app.war"
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:163)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: WFLYSRV0160:
Failed to mount deployment content
at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.module.DeploymentRootMountProcessor.deploy(DeploymentRootMountProcessor.java:95)
at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:156)
... 5 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\project-path\demo\target\app.war (The system cannot find the file specified)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
    at org.jboss.vfs.spi.RootFileSystem.openInputStream(RootFileSystem.java:51)
    at org.jboss.vfs.VirtualFile.openStream(VirtualFile.java:254)
    at org.jboss.vfs.VFS.mountZipExpanded(VFS.java:533)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentMountProvider$Factory$ServerDeploymentRepositoryImpl.mountDeploymentContent(DeploymentMountProvider.java:108)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.module.DeploymentRootMountProcessor.deploy(DeploymentRootMountProcessor.java:91)
    ... 6 more

[INFO]...//(omitted for brevity)

ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "app.war")]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"app.war\".STRUCTURE" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"app.war\".STRUCTURE: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase STRUCTURE of deployment \"app.war\"
    Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: WFLYSRV0160: Failed to mount deployment content
    Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\\project-path\\demo\\target\\app.war (The system cannot find the file specified)"}}
21:08:21,658 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "app.war" (runtime-name : "app.war")
21:08:21,667 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0183: Service status report
WFLYCTL0186:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.deployment.unit."app.war".STRUCTURE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."app.war".STRUCTURE: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase STRUCTURE of deployment "app.war"

INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0060: Http management interface listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990/management
20:32:13,137 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0051: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990
20:32:13,137 ERROR [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0026: WildFly Full 9.0.1.Final (WildFly Core 1.0.1.Final) started (with errors) in 7442ms - Started 205 of 383 services (1 services failed or missing dependencies, 211 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)
Connected to server
[2015-10-24 08:32:15,100] Artifact demo:war: Artifact is being deployed, please wait...

[INFO]... //(omitted for brevity)

WFLYCTL0186:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.deployment.unit."app.war".STRUCTURE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."app.war".STRUCTURE: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase STRUCTURE of deployment "app.war"
[2015-10-24 08:32:30,629] Artifact demo:war: Artifact is deployed successfully
```

So essentially it means demo gets deployed fine, but in the process it can't find one file.

***Notice this line;***

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\project-path\demo\target\app.war (The system cannot find the file specified)
```

Now this is quite strange as this file **`app.war`** shouldn't even exist in the context of **`demo`** anylonger because I had already done a complete refactoring. After inspecting the whole **`demo`** directory and not finding any reference to **`app.war`** then I thought it might just be an intelliJ referencing issue, so I undeployed **`demo`** cleaned the project, closed intelliJ, deleted the ***.idea*** folder and created a new maven project from the existing sources. Hoping this would clear any residues of **`app`** that may exist in **`demo`**, I ran **`demo`** again, but hit the same exception again.

***Also, notice the first line in the pasted StackTrace;***

```
INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYSRV0027: Starting deployment of "app.war" (runtime-name: "app.war")
```

This shows that Wildfly is first of all attempting to deploy **`app.war`** whereas it's **`demo.war`** that should be getting deployed because what i'm running is the **`demo`** project.

After everything, this leaves me suspecting the problem has to be in the scope of Wildfly, and that I might need to remove old references somewhere within Wildfly, but I am lost on ideas of what might be the underlying problem. Help would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved this already. Turned out this wasn't particularly an intellij issue.

For some reason, I found that in ***standalone.xml***, the following lines  that normally get automatically added at runtime *(and always automatically removed when application is stopped)* just refused to go...

```
<deployments>
    <deployment name="app.war" runtime-name="app.war">
            <fs-archive path="C:\project-path\demo\target\app.war"/>
    </deployment>
</deployments>
```

So I simply went in there and deleted those lines, so **voila! error be gone!**

Comment: I had this issue too and I use IntelliJ, so maybe it is caused by IntelliJ?

Comment: hmm... perhaps intelli-j is responsible for inserting those lines... I would never know, because it's been a long time ago and this issue hasn't re-occurred as far as I know

Comment: I had like 5 entries in this section. :/

Answer (score 0):

logon to jboss admin console and remove old application and restart jboss in intellij.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35427894)